# How do not redirect to /public_html if request is equaled /abc/* for example?

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, subdirectory, public-html

There is such a structure of directories:

```
/public_html
/abc
.htaccess
```

Now all requests go to the folder /public_html. This is the code of .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !public_html/
RewriteRule (.*) /public_html/$1 [L]
```

What should I do for that the requests like `[the website address]/abc/*` redirect to the folder /abc instead of /public_html?

Something like that:

> example.com/* - go to /public_html
>
> example.com/abc/* - go to /abc

Thanks! And I'm sorry for my English!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !public_html/
```

Means that you want to rewrite if the REQUEST_URI does not contain `public_html/`. So to make sure you are not rewriting a URI with `abc/` you need another condition that says so add

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !abc/
```

after the first RewriteCond and it should work. Now you say that if it does not contain either abc/ or public_html/ rewrite the url.